# Problem with Ubuntu install onto secondary HDD, no GRUB

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have two drives in my Dell Inspiron N5010 laptop. One Samsung SSD and one Hitachi HDD via HDD frame. I tried to install Ubuntu onto my HDD. I made a partition for Ubuntu. In the beginning of the install I didn’t see the partitions just the hard drive. I thought it’s not a big deal I install it alongside Windows 7. According to my searching the installer would have to ask the size of Ubuntu partition. It did not. The installer began. It was strange but I did not care. After the installer finished and the laptop rebooted the grub rescure booted. Great. I started the Ubuntu in Try mode and I saw the HDD drive was formatted and the Ubuntu istalled on this drive. WHAT? – I thought. 
The Ubuntu istaller formatted my HDD with all datas on it.

Could you please help me? I really would like to use Ubuntu. Unfortunately I can’t shrink my SSD drive (C:) because only 5GB allowed. I would like to make two partitions on my HDD drive and install the Ubuntu  onto one partition.

I am sorry about my english if there’s any mistake.

Comment: Hey Guys!

Thank you for your help!
Finally I installed it onto my primary SSD drive (C:, sda).
There was several problems like GRUB didn't started.
Anyway, I am using Ubuntu and ready to work :)

Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make any partitions on the HDD, just leave some empty space before starting the installer.

What probably happened is that you selected you HDD to install on and it had no free space available and it asked if you wanted to use the whole drive. You probably mist this and clicked next.

Comment: There is enough space (at least 300gb) on the HDD. I tried that way when I left some empty space or I formatted in ext4 format. The installer sees the whole HDD drive formatted NTFS

Comment: All right... I create an empty partition and it is good now...
That's wierd. Anyway.
The install was succesfful to sdb2 partition. After restart the Windows starts automatically.
Any ideas? Do I have to install GRUB manually?

Answer (score 1):

When you installing Ubuntu, don't select "Install It alongside Windows 7".

Look at the last line, you will see "Something else", select It and now, you can see partitions in your HDD. Select partition you want and click "Install now".

Comment: I tried it, but I don't see partitions on the secondary HDD.
Maybe I should try It again...